# Three events in one probability space

Tags: probability, random-variables

Consider three random variables :

1. The result of rolling the dice.
2. The number of reverse in three coin toss.
3. $\lfloor x^2 \rfloor$, $x\in [-2,2]$

Can we describe above random variables on the one, standard probability space?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking for here.  Are these meant to be independent variables?  What's a "reverse"?  Of course, you can always just write your space as a product of the three spaces (assuming you wanted independence).

Comment: Reverse it is one of the side of the coin. Random variables do not have to be independent.

Comment: Ah, so if it's an ordinary coin we might just say "Tails", yes?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: And what about my questions on dependence?  Did you understand my proposal about the product space?  I'm proposing triples $(x,y,z)$ where $x$ denotes the result of a fair dice roll, $y$ the number of Tails seen in three tosses of a fair coin, and $z$, the result of drawing a random real number between $-2$ and $2$ abd computing $\lfloor x^2 \rfloor$.  Does that make sense?

Comment: If that is the sort of thing you had in mind, then the space is $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\times \{0,1,2,3\} \times \{0,1,2,3,4\}$, though of course you still need to assign probabilities to the elements of that space.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your note on independence.  If you want to allow for dependence then of course we can't assign probabilities...they will now depend on the nature of the dependence.

Comment: Hmm..What about sigma-algebra ? Could it be done without using cartesian product. For example $\Omega =[0,1]$?

Comment: Do you mean the closed interval $[0,1]$ or the points $0$ and $1$?  If the latter, no.  If the former...well, you should be able to map my space to the interval if that's what you want.  Not sure there's a natural such interpretation though.

Comment: I meant interval.